# std::logic_error when trying to return a std::string

Tags: c++

I have written some code using a class that will display the measurements of a box. I am doing so by having the output in a `toString()` method and it appears to be working but when i run the program I get the following error:

```
Height: 1 Width: 1 Depth: 1terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Then the program chrashes. Also I've noticed that the program doesn't display the volume after the 3 dimensions.

**Here is the code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>      // for output formatting
#include <stdexcept>    // for out_of_range
#include <sstream>      // for stringstream
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>      // for system()

using namespace std;

class Box 
{

    public:
        // Constructors
        Box(double height=1, double width=1, double depth=1);

        // Mutators
        void setHeight(double height);
        void setWidth(double width);
        void setDepth(double depth);

        // Accessors
        double getHeight() const {return (boxHeight);};
        double getWidth() const {return (boxWidth);};
        double getDepth() const {return (boxDepth);};
        double getVolume() const; 
        string toString() ;
    private:
        double boxHeight;
        double boxWidth;
        double boxDepth;
        double boxVolume;
};

int main()
{

    cout << "\nBox Mesurement!";
    cout << "\n===============";
    cout << endl;

    Box boxDem(true);

// WHERE THE STRING IS DISPLAYED
        cout << "\n" << boxDem.toString();
        cout<< endl;    
        cout << "\n" << boxDem.getVolume();

    return 0;
}

Box::Box(double height, double width, double depth)
{
    setHeight(height);
    setWidth(width);
    setDepth(depth);
}

void Box::setHeight(double height)
{
    const double MIN = 0.01;

    if (height > 0 && height < MIN)
    {
        height = 0.01;
        boxHeight = height;
    }
    else if (height < 0)
    {
        height *= -1;
        boxHeight = height;
    }
    else 
    {
        boxHeight = height;
    }
}
void Box::setWidth(double width)
{
    const double MIN = 0.01;

    if (width > 0 && width < MIN)
    {
        width = 0.01;
        boxWidth = width;
    }
    else if (width < 0)
    {
        width *= -1;
        boxWidth = width;
    }
    else 
    {
        boxWidth = width;
    }
}
void Box::setDepth(double depth)
{
    const double MIN = 0.01;

    if (depth > 0 && depth < MIN)
    {
        depth = 0.01;
        boxDepth = depth;
    }
    else if (depth < 0)
    {
        depth *= -1;
        boxDepth = depth;
    }
    else 
    {
        boxDepth = depth;
    }
}

double Box::getVolume() const
{
    double volume = 0.0;

    volume = getHeight() * getHeight() *getDepth();

    return volume;

}

// WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
    string Box::toString() 
    {
        cout << "Height: " << getHeight() << " Width: " << getWidth() << " Depth: " << getDepth();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your function says it returns a `string`yet you return the number `0`.

Comment: This isn't an [mcve]; there is a lot of code that can be cut down to produce something that is compilable but still shows this error

Comment: @Galik I should have also mentioned that i tried to put return toString(); but that would just have it repeat over and over again nonstop

Comment: @Brett You need to create a `string` before you can return one. Returning a number instead was never going to work.

Comment: OMG.  I was like, "Why does that even compile," and then I realized what it's attempting to do.  FUGLY!  Yeah, that's where the problem is :p  @Galik called it.  You're lucky you got an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cout` is meant to output stuff to the command line, but you are writing a function that's supposed to return a `string`, that makes little sense.

`ostringstream` is a neat class that allows you to build strings using the same mechanisms as `cout`, try this:

```
string Box::toString() 
{
    std::ostringstream result;
    result << "Height: " << getHeight() << " Width: " << getWidth() << " Depth: " << getDepth();
    return result.str();
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for you help, I just wanted to ask you another question. When i change the dimensions of the box it seems to be giving me the wrong volume. For example, i set the height to 13, the width to 5, and the depth to 3 and it should give me a volume of 195 but it actually gives me 507.

Comment: `getHeight() * getHeight() * getDepth()`, <- reread this, the error is pretty obvious.